# phpmyadmin: DROP DATABASE statements disabled

Tags: phpmyadmin

I just upgraded from 10.04 to 12.04.

Now, when I try to drop a database in *phpmyadmin* it gives me an error saying that `DROP DATABASE` statements are disabled.

After reading up on this I added this line

```
$cfg['AllowUserDropDatabase'] = true;
```

to the bottom of `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`, but I still get the same message.

I logged out of *phpmyadmin*, rebooted and logged back in, but still no change.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

OK, I have discovered a few more details:

- I can drop a database from PHPMyadmin by clicking on the DROP link.  I can not, however, drop by typing the SQL directly.
- I can drop a database from the command prompt, no problems
- There is one particular database that seems to be screwed up.  If I try to DROP from the command prompt, it says it has lost connection to the server.  If I try from within PHPMyadmin, it errors out and logs me out instantly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4410630/632951

Answer (score 3):

if you are using version 4+ then you can simply drop a database just following these steps:

1. go to mysql admin
2. click database option (right side of your databases)
3. here you will get all the databases you have and now click the checkbox at the left side of the databases you want to delete
4. just the bottom of these databases you can see the option "Drop" so click the drop to delete the database permanently

Answer (score 2):

You will need to update file

```
config.default
```

generally phpmyadmin's libraries folder

line 653 (may very depending on version)

```
$cfg['AllowUserDropDatabase'] = true;
```

(restart your MySQL once the value is changed to 'true')

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me.

1. `sudo service mysql restart`
2. Open **phpmyadmin**
3. Click on **Databases** in the header.
4. Marked **database_to_delete**.
5. Select `drop` action.